# Nav bar accordion link not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have a nav bar that contains another page of my site, the page listed in the nav bar has a drop down list that is going to be linked to an accordion on the specific page. I'm having trouble implementing it, that if one of the drop down list items is click, then you will be taken to the page and the particular accordion linked to the item will be open.

For testing purposes I only have the nav bar list item "Monitoring" accordion linked right now; when I click "Monitoring" it takes me to the right page, but the accordion is still closed.

### Here's my nav bar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color: #6F9824; text-align:center ">
    <div class="navbar-header" align="center">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" style="color:white;" align="center"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="color:white;" align="center">
            <li>
            <a asp-page="/Index" style="color:white;">Home</a>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="color:white;">
                        Centrify
                        <span class="caret"></span>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="/Centrify">Centrify Home</a></li>

                            <li><a href="/Centrify?panel=1#Accordion1">Monitoring</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Patching</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Onboarding</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Disaster Recovery</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Reporting</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
    </div>
</nav>
```

### Accordion I'm trying to open:

```
<div id="Accordion1" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="2">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
                <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                    Vault Status
                </a>
            </h5>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="2">
            <div class="card-block">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Select Environment</label>
                    <select multiple class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2">
                        <option>RTP</option>
                        <option>OMA</option>
                        <option>BGI</option>
                        <option>BG2</option>
                        <option>CLD</option>
                        <option>WRKSTN</option>
                        <option>QA</option>
                    </select><br />
                    <button>Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

### JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $("#Accordion1").accordion();
});

function getParam(name) {
    var query = location.search.substring(1);
    if (query.length) {
        var parts = query.split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
            var pos = parts[i].indexOf('=');
            if (parts[i].substring(0, pos) == name) {
                return parts[i].substring(pos + 1);

            }

        }

    }
    return 0;
}

$(function() {
    var defaultPanel = parseInt(getParam('panel'));
    $("#Accordion1").accordion({
        active: defaultPanel
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that's what's causing the problem, but the end of you'r `<ul>` and first `<li>` is missing on you'r first HTML code

Answer (score 0):

How do you expect your accordion to work if there are no headers? [According to jQuery UI documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/), your HTML should look something like

```
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>First header</h3>
  <div>First content panel</div>
  <h3>Second header</h3>
  <div>Second content panel</div>
</div>
```

but it does not. You need pairs header-content in order for it to work.